# Websphere ND Object Cache instances not replicating within accepted timeframe

Tags: java, caching, replication, websphere-7, ibm-was

I got a Websphere ND environment with 1 cluster and 2 runtimesin it.I also have a object cache and enabled replication in them.I got push and pull mode.So if i put one object in cache it replicates in the other.But when I load test my system I see that sometimes the replication has not happened within my acceptable time frame.ANy pointers?

Comment: Try to switch only to push mode. If it wont help I'd suggest opening PMR in IBM Support.

Comment: Thank You. I shall try push mode. Otherwise thats the next step

Comment: Hi @Gas.replication happens under general cases and it starts to fail only when i do massive load testing.So do you think push might fix it?

Comment: Check this paper for some tips related to [tuning DRS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006431). You may try to tweak some parameters.

Comment: @Gas - I did all possible changes.But looks like replication is not even happening because we waited for 9 seconds and still not finding my item in cache.So is there some monitoring that i can enable in addition to PMR?I am specifically interested in object cache and not the dyna cache.Also is their any relation between the object cache and dyna cache.becoz i have not enabled dyna cache replication in this cluster

Comment: @Gas -please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488191/unable-to-find-was-nd-object-cache-instance-full-group-replication-domain-proper