# Unable to find WAS ND Object cache Instance full group replication domain property variable name

Tags: java, caching, ibm-was, wsadmin

I got WAS ND 7

Logged into admin console. Resources -> Cache Instances->Created new Object cache instance. Under consistency settings I got Full Group Relication Domain drop down list. I selected one of the replication domains that I created

All is good

Now I want to create exactly the same cache instance via wsadmin applyconfig task by feeding a property file to it

I referred [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_config_prop_cacheprovider_objc.html) and see that all the property names are there except the one for Full Group Replication Domain. I tried to guess it like fullGroupReplicationDomain and it isnt working. Any help? When I create the instance via property file i am not able to select the replication domain of my choice and a default 1 is assigned.

Is this is a problem with the WAS Property File thing itself as I can't see a equivalent property there? Please see second image

Have uploaded the images from both Admin Console and Property Configuration
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Gas - pls help if possible

Comment: Did you try to export configuration done via console? See if any replication related property will be there.

Comment: Yes. I did. I exported 1 from my dev environment and tried to apply that to my QA env. Cannot see that property there

Comment: Then I'd suggest opening PMR in IBM support, if it is missing in export.